# The docker CI pipeline is failing during execution of bash script

Tags: bash, docker

I am facing a problem in creating CI for docker containers. During CI build I have to remove the previous docker container and image, in this case, the build is failing when there is not any image on the server.

How can I execute this statement without stopping the build to fail?

```
docker rmi example/hello-world:latest

Unable to find image 'example/hello-world:latest' locally
docker: Error response from daemon:
```

The build is not failing in the `docker stop` and `docker rm` case:

```
docker stop zod || true && docker rm zod || true
```

How do I make sure the build doesn't fail if the image doesn't exist on the server?

This is my script for docker deployement:

```
docker build -t example/hello-world:latest .
docker stop zod || true && docker rm zod || true
docker rmi example/hello-world:latest
docker run --name zod -d -p 6000:6000 -dit example/hello-world:latest
```

Comment: Well you are already setup so you ignore failure to stop and rm zod, why not do the same thing with the hello-world call?

Comment: @Randommm I try the following statement but the build is still failing, I don't know why in the `rmi` case it is not working. `docker rmi example/hello-world:latest || true`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First check if the image exists, then remove it:

```
exists=$(docker images example/hello-world:latest | tail -n +2)
if [ -z $exists ]
then
 docker rmi example/hello-world:latest
fi
```

Comment: `bash: -c: line 4: syntax error near unexpected token)`

`bash: -c: line 4: exists=$(docker images example/hello-world:latest | tail -n +2))`

Comment: sorry, I had an extra `)`. I edited the answer

Comment: Thanks the pipeline is now working fine, I am accepting your answer, but can you give some explanation of the snippet like What is the meaning of `-z` and `square brackes`.

Comment: Happy to help :). The tail removes the header line from the output of `docker images`.The square brackets are a synonym for the "test" command, and the -z checks if the $exists value is 0 (empty).